# add a curve that fits the peaks from a plot in R?

Tags: r, vector, plot, curve

Is there a function that adds a curve that fits the peaks if given two vectors and their plot?
For example, I have:

> x= c(0:20)
>
> x
>    [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
>
> y
>    [1] 19.4 17.9  8.1 11.3  7.8  8.0  5.0  1.7  3.9  5.4  7.5  5.4  4.7  5.0  4.9  3.5  2.9  2.4  1.4  1.7
>
> plot(x,y,xlim=range(x),ylim=range(y))

best,
Nanami

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'fits the peaks'?

Comment: I mean a curve that follows the trend of the values, but doesn't take into consideration every value. I've tried doing this with loess - but with that I obtain a curve that fits the whole date and I want to take into consideration the highest and the lowest value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, your problem is very poorly defined.  You supply a range of discrete values, not a function, for your y values.  This means it can not be differentiated to find local maxima.

That said, here is a bit of code that might get you started.  It makes use of a function called `peaks`, ([attributed to Brian Ripley](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02a/archive/33097.html)):

```
peaks<-function(series,span=3){
  z <- embed(series, span)
  s <- span%/%2
  v<- max.col(z) == 1 + s
  result <- c(rep(FALSE,s),v)
  result <- result[1:(length(result)-s)]
  result
} 

x <- c(1:20)
y <- c(19.4, 17.9, 8.1, 11.3, 7.8, 8.0, 5.0, 1.7, 3.9, 
       5.4, 7.5, 5.4, 4.7, 5.0, 4.9, 3.5, 2.9, 2.4, 1.4, 1.7)

plot(x,y, type="l")
p <- which(peaks(y, span=3))

lines(x[p], y[p], col="red", type="b)
```

[image]

The problem is that the concept of local peaks is poorly defined.  How local do you mean?  The peaks algorithm as supplied allows you to modify the `span`.  Have a play and see whether it is helpful at all.

Comment: so, it would be better to use directly the function that I am given to compute the y values? For example if have: y<-v(i)*100/sum(v) where v is an input vector how should I handle this?

Comment: Unless `v` is a continuous function you will still have the same problem.