# Detecting dips in a 2D plot

Tags: r, signal-processing

I need to automatically detect dips in a 2D plot, like the regions marked with red circles in the figure below. I'm only interested in the "main" dips, meaning the dips have to span a minimum length in the x axis. The number of dips is unknown, i.e., different plots will contain different numbers of dips. Any ideas?

[image: Dips in a 2D plot]

**Update:**

As requested, here's the sample data, together with an attempt to smooth it using median filtering, as suggested by vines.

Looks like I need now a robust way to approximate the derivative at each point that would ignore the little blips that remain in the data. Is there any standard approach?

```
y <- c(0.9943,0.9917,0.9879,0.9831,0.9553,0.9316,0.9208,0.9119,0.8857,0.7951,0.7605,0.8074,0.7342,0.6374,0.6035,0.5331,0.4781,0.4825,0.4825,0.4879,0.5374,0.4600,0.3668,0.3456,0.4282,0.3578,0.3630,0.3399,0.3578,0.4116,0.3762,0.3668,0.4420,0.4749,0.4556,0.4458,0.5084,0.5043,0.5043,0.5331,0.4781,0.5623,0.6604,0.5900,0.5084,0.5802,0.5802,0.6174,0.6124,0.6374,0.6827,0.6906,0.7034,0.7418,0.7817,0.8311,0.8001,0.7912,0.7912,0.7540,0.7951,0.7817,0.7644,0.7912,0.8311,0.8311,0.7912,0.7688,0.7418,0.7232,0.7147,0.6906,0.6715,0.6681,0.6374,0.6516,0.6650,0.6604,0.6124,0.6334,0.6374,0.5514,0.5514,0.5412,0.5514,0.5374,0.5473,0.4825,0.5084,0.5126,0.5229,0.5126,0.5043,0.4379,0.4781,0.4600,0.4781,0.3806,0.4078,0.3096,0.3263,0.3399,0.3184,0.2820,0.2167,0.2122,0.2080,0.2558,0.2255,0.1921,0.1766,0.1732,0.1205,0.1732,0.0723,0.0701,0.0405,0.0643,0.0771,0.1018,0.0587,0.0884,0.0884,0.1240,0.1088,0.0554,0.0607,0.0441,0.0387,0.0490,0.0478,0.0231,0.0414,0.0297,0.0701,0.0502,0.0567,0.0405,0.0363,0.0464,0.0701,0.0832,0.0991,0.1322,0.1998,0.3146,0.3146,0.3184,0.3578,0.3311,0.3184,0.4203,0.3578,0.3578,0.3578,0.4282,0.5084,0.5802,0.5667,0.5473,0.5514,0.5331,0.4749,0.4037,0.4116,0.4203,0.3184,0.4037,0.4037,0.4282,0.4513,0.4749,0.4116,0.4825,0.4918,0.4879,0.4918,0.4825,0.4245,0.4333,0.4651,0.4879,0.5412,0.5802,0.5126,0.4458,0.5374,0.4600,0.4600,0.4600,0.4600,0.3992,0.4879,0.4282,0.4333,0.3668,0.3005,0.3096,0.3847,0.3939,0.3630,0.3359,0.2292,0.2292,0.2748,0.3399,0.2963,0.2963,0.2385,0.2531,0.1805,0.2531,0.2786,0.3456,0.3399,0.3491,0.4037,0.3885,0.3806,0.2748,0.2700,0.2657,0.2963,0.2865,0.2167,0.2080,0.1844,0.2041,0.1602,0.1416,0.2041,0.1958,0.1018,0.0744,0.0677,0.0909,0.0789,0.0723,0.0660,0.1322,0.1532,0.1060,0.1018,0.1060,0.1150,0.0789,0.1266,0.0965,0.1732,0.1766,0.1766,0.1805,0.2820,0.3096,0.2602,0.2080,0.2333,0.2385,0.2385,0.2432,0.1602,0.2122,0.2385,0.2333,0.2558,0.2432,0.2292,0.2209,0.2483,0.2531,0.2432,0.2432,0.2432,0.2432,0.3053,0.3630,0.3578,0.3630,0.3668,0.3263,0.3992,0.4037,0.4556,0.4703,0.5173,0.6219,0.6412,0.7275,0.6984,0.6756,0.7079,0.7192,0.7342,0.7458,0.7501,0.7540,0.7605,0.7605,0.7342,0.7912,0.7951,0.8036,0.8074,0.8074,0.8118,0.7951,0.8118,0.8242,0.8488,0.8650,0.8488,0.8311,0.8424,0.7912,0.7951,0.8001,0.8001,0.7458,0.7192,0.6984,0.6412,0.6516,0.5900,0.5802,0.5802,0.5762,0.5623,0.5374,0.4556,0.4556,0.4333,0.3762,0.3456,0.4037,0.3311,0.3263,0.3311,0.3717,0.3762,0.3717,0.3668,0.3491,0.4203,0.4037,0.4149,0.4037,0.3992,0.4078,0.4651,0.4967,0.5229,0.5802,0.5802,0.5846,0.6293,0.6412,0.6374,0.6604,0.7317,0.7034,0.7573,0.7573,0.7573,0.7772,0.7605,0.8036,0.7951,0.7817,0.7869,0.7724,0.7869,0.7869,0.7951,0.7644,0.7912,0.7275,0.7342,0.7275,0.6984,0.7342,0.7605,0.7418,0.7418,0.7275,0.7573,0.7724,0.8118,0.8521,0.8823,0.8984,0.9119,0.9316,0.9512)

yy <- runmed(y, 41)
plot(y, type="l", ylim=c(0,1), ylab="", xlab="", lwd=0.5)
points(yy, col="blue", type="l", lwd=2)
```

[image: Median filtering]

Comment: I guess you could smooth the data a bit and use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324354/add-a-curve-that-fits-the-peaks-from-a-plot-in-r/

Comment: sample data would have been nice...

Comment: @Joris I've added the data used to generate the plot. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thx for the data. Find the answer below

Comment: I think this question belongs on crossvalidated - this is really a statistical question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDITED : *function strips the regions to contain nothing but the lowest part, if wanted.*

Actually, Using the mean is easier than using the median. This allows you to find regions where the real values are continuously below the mean. The median is not smooth enough for an easy application.

One example function to do this would be :

```
FindLowRegion <- function(x,n=length(x)/4,tol=length(x)/20,p=0.5){
    nx <- length(x)
    n <-  2*(n %/% 2) + 1
    # smooth out based on means
    sx <- rowMeans(embed(c(rep(NA,n/2),x,rep(NA,n/2)),n),na.rm=T)
    # find which series are far from the mean
    rlesx <- rle((sx-x)>0)
    # construct start and end of regions
    int <- embed(cumsum(c(1,rlesx$lengths)),2)
    # which regions fulfill requirements
    id <- rlesx$value & rlesx$length > tol
    # Cut regions to be in general smaller than median
    regions <-
    apply(int[id,],1,function(i){
        i <- min(i):max(i)
        tmp <- x[i]
        id <- which(tmp < quantile(tmp,p))
        id <- min(id):max(id)
        i[id]            
    })
    # return
    unlist(regions)
}
```

where

- `n` determines how much values are used to calculate the running mean,
- `tol` determines how many consecutive values should be lower than the running mean to talk about a low region, and
- `p` determines the cutoff used (as a quantile) for stripping the regions to their lowest part. When p=1, the complete lower region is shown.

Function is tweaked to work on data as you presented, but the numbers might need to be adjusted a bit to work with other data.

This function returns a set of indices, which allows you to find the low regions. Illustrated with your y vector :

```
Lows <- FindLowRegion(y)

newx <- seq_along(y)
newy <- ifelse(newx %in% Lows,y,NA)
plot(y, col="blue", type="l", lwd=2)
lines(newx,newy,col="red",lwd="3")
```

Gives :

[image]

Comment: @Hadley : about as much as loess() and friends.

Comment: In your statement `newy <- ifelse(x %in% Lows,y,NA)`, where does `x` come from? Shouldn't that be `newx`?

Comment: @bill_080: That's true, it should be `newx`.

Comment: @bill_080 @Leo : indeed. I overlooked the typo, sorry. thx for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

You have to smooth the graph in some way. `Median filtration` is quite useful for that purpose (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). After smoothing, you will simply have to search for the minima, just as usual (i.e. search for the points where the 1st derivative switches from negative to positive).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question with median filtering. There's still some noise, so one problem remains: robust approximation of the 1st derivative.

Comment: @Leo: I know virtually nothing about R... But speaking algorithmically, first thing I'd try is a sliding window: when all the points in the window, except for leftmost and rightmost ones, are below the lowest of leftmost and rightmost, then a dip is found, and the window is shifted by its width at once, otherwise the window is shifted by a single step...

Comment: @Joris Meys: I'd say, in general it depends on the character of noise in the data..

Comment: for the smoothing itself you're right. For the detection of minima and maxima, you can use the 'limitations' of the mean in the sense that the mean will almost always over- resp. underestimate the real values at minima resp maxima. That was more my point.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer (which also does not require smoothing) could be provided by adapting the `maxdrawdown()` function from the [tseries](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tseries).  A *drawdown* is commonly defined as the retreat from the most-recent maximum; here we want the opposite.   Such a function could then be used in a sliding window over the data, or over segmented data.

```
maxdrawdown <- function(x) {
    if(NCOL(x) > 1)
        stop("x is not a vector or univariate time series")
    if(any(is.na(x)))
        stop("NAs in x")
    cmaxx <- cummax(x)-x
    mdd <- max(cmaxx)
    to <- which(mdd == cmaxx)
    from <- double(NROW(to))
    for (i in 1:NROW(to))
        from[i] <- max(which(cmaxx[1:to[i]] == 0))
    return(list(maxdrawdown = mdd, from = from, to = to))
}
```

So instead of using `cummax()`, one would have to switch to `cummin()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was something much cruder than filtering. Why not look for the big drops followed by long enough stable periods?

```
span.b <- 20
threshold.b <- 0.2
dy.b <- c(rep(NA, span.b), diff(y, lag = span.b))
span.f <- 10
threshold.f <- 0.05
dy.f <- c(diff(y, lag = span.f), rep(NA, span.f))
down <- which(dy.b < -1 * threshold.b & abs(dy.f) < threshold.f)
abline(v = down)
```

The plot shows that it's not perfect, but it doesn't discard the outliers (I guess it depends on your take on the data).