# Signal processing: How to patch over dip in signal using R?

Tags: r, signal-processing

Could anybody please help me solve my problem I encountered when working in signal processing in R?

**Problem**
I have a recording of a signal in a form of 2 columns (x=row number, y=intensity) with some well defined drops in the signal.

My signal with drops in the signal highlighted by red arrows:
[image: My signal with drops in the signal highlighted by red arrows]

I would like to bridge these drops using a simple line anchored at the manually selected endpoints as shown below.

How it should look in the end:
[image: How it should look in the end:)]

I can manually get coordinations of the end points (X,Y):
[image: I can manually get coordinations of the end points (X,Y).]

Example data: [exampleData](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkL9yeOEWb1cP8jNaDWFnanGckfSJ28c/view?usp=sharing)

**My idea of solution:**

I go through the acquisition files, manually collect the start (X1,Y1) and end (X2,Y2) points coordinates for each acquisition, save as .csv file

Have a script which calculates line segments connecting these endpoints in form of two columns ranging from X1 to X2 in rwo numbers, Y1 to Y2 in intensity.

Have a script replaces that the dip in the original data with the line segment.

**What I do not know:**

How to make a function which based on start (X1, Y1) and end point (X2, Y2) coordinates generates X2-X1 rows with values from Y1 to Y2.

**Thank you very much for help and suggestions Vladimir**

Notes:
I have some 50 files to go through.

There can be more dips in the signal in given acquisition file.

Example data here:

```
dput(dataInput[1:2500,])
structure(list(X = 0:2499, Y = c(87, 87.3333, 86.3333, 85.6667, 
85.3333, 86, 85, 84.6667, 85, 84, 83.6667, 83, 82, 82, 82.3333, 
81.6667, 82.3333, 81.3333, 80.6667, 79.6667, 80.3333, 79.3333, 
79, 79, 78.3333, 78.6667, 77.6667, 78, 77.3333, 78, 76.6667, 
77, 76.3333, 75.6667, 75.3333, 74.6667, 75.6667, 74.3333, 73.6667, 
74.3333, 74, 73.6667, 74.3333, 72.6667, 72.6667, 72.3333, 73, 
72, 72.6667, 71.6667, 71, 71.3333, 71.6667, 70.6667, 70, 70.6667, 
70.6667, 69.6667, 69.6667, 69, 68.6667, 68, 69, 68.6667, 68, 
68, 66.6667, 67, 67.3333, 66.3333, 67, 66.3333, 66.3333, 66.6667, 
66, 65.6667, 66, 65.3333, 65.6667, 64.6667, 65, 64.6667, 64.3333, 
63.6667, 63.6667, 64, 64, 63.3333, 63, 63.3333, 62.6667, 62.6667, 
62.3333, 62, 62.6667, 62, 61.3333, 61.3333, 61.3333, 61, 61, 
61.6667, 61.3333, 61.6667, 60.6667, 60.6667, 60, 59.6667, 59.6667, 
59.3333, 59.6667, 59.3333, 60, 58.3333, 58.6667, 58.3333, 59.3333, 
59, 58, 58, 58, 57, 58.3333, 58.3333, 58, 57.3333, 57.3333, 57.3333, 
58, 56.6667, 57, 56.6667, 56, 56.6667, 56, 56.6667, 56.6667, 
56, 55.6667, 56, 55.6667, 54.3333, 55.3333, 55, 54.6667, 55.3333, 
54.6667, 55, 54, 54.6667, 54.3333, 54.3333, 54.6667, 54, 54.3333, 
53.6667, 54, 54, 52.6667, 53.6667, 53.3333, 53, 53.3333, 52.6667, 
53, 53, 52.6667, 52, 52.3333, 52.3333, 52, 52.3333, 52, 52, 51.6667, 
51.6667, 52, 51.3333, 50.3333, 50.3333, 52, 51.3333, 51.3333, 
51, 50.6667, 51.3333, 51, 50, 51, 50.6667, 51, 50.6667, 50.6667, 
50.6667, 50.6667, 50.3333, 50.3333, 51, 49.6667, 50.6667, 49.6667, 
49.3333, 49.6667, 49.3333, 49, 49.6667, 49.3333, 49.3333, 48.6667, 
48.6667, 48.6667, 48.6667, 48.6667, 48, 48, 48.3333, 49, 48.3333, 
49, 48.3333, 48, 47.3333, 48, 48.3333, 47.6667, 47.6667, 47.6667, 
48, 47.6667, 47.3333, 47.6667, 48, 47.6667, 47.3333, 46.3333, 
47.3333, 47, 46.6667, 46.6667, 46.3333, 47, 46.6667, 46, 46, 
46.6667, 47, 46.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 
46, 46, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45, 45.6667, 
45.6667, 45, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 45.3333, 45, 44.6667, 
45.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 44.3333, 45, 45, 45.3333, 45.3333, 
44.6667, 44.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 44.6667, 44.3333, 43.6667, 
44.3333, 44, 44.3333, 45, 43.6667, 44, 43.6667, 44, 44, 43, 43.6667, 
43.3333, 44, 44.3333, 43.6667, 43.3333, 43.6667, 43.3333, 44.3333, 
43.3333, 43.3333, 43, 43.3333, 44, 42.6667, 43.3333, 43.6667, 
43, 43, 44, 42.6667, 43.6667, 43.3333, 42.6667, 43, 42, 41.6667, 
42.6667, 42.6667, 42.6667, 42, 43, 41.6667, 42.3333, 42, 41.6667, 
41.6667, 41.6667, 41.3333, 42, 41.6667, 42, 42, 41.6667, 42, 
42, 42, 41.3333, 41.6667, 42, 42, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41.6667, 
41.3333, 40.6667, 41, 40.6667, 41, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41, 41.6667, 
40.3333, 40.3333, 41.3333, 40, 41.3333, 40.3333, 41.3333, 40, 
41.6667, 41.3333, 40.6667, 40.6667, 41, 40, 40, 40.6667, 40.3333, 
41, 40.3333, 40.6667, 40.3333, 40.3333, 40, 40.6667, 40, 40.6667, 
40, 40, 40.3333, 40, 40, 40, 40.3333, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.6667, 
40, 40, 40.6667, 40.3333, 40.6667, 39.6667, 40.3333, 39, 40, 
40, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.3333, 39.3333, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.6667, 
39.6667, 39, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.3333, 39.3333, 40, 39.6667, 
39.6667, 38.6667, 39.3333, 39.6667, 39, 38.6667, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39.3333, 39.3333, 39, 37.6667, 38.6667, 39, 39.3333, 39.3333, 
39, 38.6667, 38.6667, 38.6667, 39, 38.3333, 39, 38.3333, 37.6667, 
38, 39, 38.3333, 39, 38.3333, 38, 38, 38.6667, 38.3333, 39, 38, 
38.3333, 38.3333, 38, 38.3333, 38, 38, 37.6667, 39.3333, 38.3333, 
38.3333, 37.6667, 37.6667, 38, 37.3333, 37.6667, 37.6667, 37.6667, 
38, 38, 38, 37.6667, 38, 38, 37.6667, 38, 37.3333, 37.3333, 37.3333, 
37.3333, 37.3333, 37, 37, 37.6667, 37, 37.3333, 37.3333, 37.6667, 
37, 37.6667, 37.6667, 37, 37, 37.3333, 37, 37.3333, 37, 36.6667, 
37, 37, 37, 37.6667, 37.3333, 36.3333, 37.3333, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
37, 37, 36.6667, 36.6667, 37, 36.6667, 37.3333, 36.3333, 36, 
36.6667, 37, 36.3333, 36.3333, 37, 36.6667, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
36.6667, 37, 37, 37, 36.6667, 36, 36.3333, 36.6667, 36.3333, 
36.6667, 36.3333, 36.6667, 36.6667, 36, 36.3333, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
36, 36.3333, 36, 36, 36.3333, 36, 36, 37, 36.6667, 36.3333, 36, 
36, 36, 35.3333, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36.3333, 
36.3333, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36, 
35.3333, 35.3333, 36, 35.3333, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 36, 36, 35.3333, 35, 36, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35.3333, 
35, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35, 36, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
36.3333, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35.3333, 35, 35.6667, 35, 
35.3333, 35.3333, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35.6667, 35, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 35, 35, 35, 35.3333, 34.3333, 35, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35.3333, 
35, 35.6667, 35, 35, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35, 35, 34.3333, 
34.6667, 35, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 
35, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 
34.6667, 34, 28.3333, 28, 28.6667, 28, 28, 28, 27.6667, 28, 27.6667, 
28.3333, 27.6667, 26.6667, 26, 25.3333, 25.3333, 25.6667, 25, 
25.3333, 25, 25, 25.3333, 25, 24.6667, 25.6667, 25, 25, 25.3333, 
24.6667, 24.6667, 24.3333, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24.6667, 25.6667, 
25, 25, 25, 25.6667, 25, 24, 24.6667, 25, 24.6667, 25, 24.6667, 
25.3333, 25.6667, 25, 25.3333, 24, 25, 24.3333, 25, 25, 25, 24.3333, 
24.6667, 24.6667, 25, 24.3333, 24.6667, 24.6667, 24, 24.3333, 
24.3333, 24.6667, 24, 24.3333, 24, 24.6667, 25, 25, 24.6667, 
24, 27.6667, 30.3333, 30.3333, 30, 30.3333, 30.3333, 30.6667, 
31.3333, 31.3333, 31, 31, 30.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31, 30.3333, 
30, 31.6667, 30.3333, 31.6667, 31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 
30.6667, 31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31.6667, 31.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 33, 
32, 32, 33, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 33.3333, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 33, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 33, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 33, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 
31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 33, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 31.6667, 33.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32, 33, 31.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 33, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
27.6667, 27.3333, 26.6667, 26, 26.3333, 26.3333, 26, 26.3333, 
26.3333, 26, 26.3333, 25.3333, 24.6667, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24.3333, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 23.3333, 24, 24, 24.3333, 23.6667, 23.3333, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
23.6667, 24, 24.3333, 24, 23.6667, 23.3333, 24, 23.6667, 24, 
24, 24, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.6667, 24, 23.6667, 
24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 25, 29, 29.3333, 29, 29, 29, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 30, 29.6667, 
29.6667, 30, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 30.3333, 30, 29.6667, 29.6667, 
29.6667, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30.3333, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 31, 31, 
31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31, 31.3333, 29.6667, 31, 
30.6667, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31, 31.3333, 30.3333, 30.6667, 
31.3333, 31, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
30.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 
31, 31, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31, 30.6667, 31.3333, 
30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 
31.6667, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.3333, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 33, 33, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 33, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.6667, 
33.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33.3333, 33, 33.3333, 
33.6667, 33, 32.6667, 33, 33.3333, 33, 33.3333, 33.6667, 33.3333, 
33, 33, 34.3333, 33.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 33, 33.6667, 33.6667, 
33.6667, 33.6667, 34.3333, 34, 34, 34.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 
34.3333, 34, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34, 33.6667, 35, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35, 
35.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36.6667, 36, 
36, 37, 37.6667, 39, 40.3333, 43.3333, 47.6667, 52, 53.3333, 
55.6667, 57.6667, 58, 58.6667, 60.6667, 61, 61.6667, 62, 61.6667, 
62.6667, 62.6667, 63.3333, 63, 64, 64.6667, 64.3333, 64.3333, 
65, 65.3333, 65, 66, 66.6667, 66, 67, 67, 67.3333, 68.3333, 67.3333, 
67.6667, 68.3333, 67.6667, 68.3333, 68.3333, 68.3333, 69, 68.6667, 
68.6667, 69.6667, 69.3333, 70, 69.6667, 70.3333, 71, 71.3333, 
70.6667, 72, 72, 72.3333, 71.6667, 71.3333, 72, 72.3333, 72.6667, 
72, 72.6667, 74, 74.3333, 74, 74, 74.3333, 74.3333, 74.3333, 
74, 74.6667, 74, 75.3333, 74.3333, 75.6667, 74.6667, 75.3333, 
75, 75.6667, 76, 75.6667, 75.3333, 76.6667, 76.6667, 77.3333, 
76.3333, 76.3333, 77, 77.6667, 77.6667, 76.6667, 78, 77.6667, 
78.6667, 78.3333, 77.3333, 78.3333, 77.6667, 78.6667, 79, 78.3333, 
79, 79, 79.3333, 79, 79.3333, 78.6667, 79.3333, 79.6667, 79.3333, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 80.3333, 80, 80.3333, 80.6667, 79.6667, 80, 
80.6667, 81.6667, 81, 80.3333, 81, 81.6667, 82, 81.3333, 82, 
82.3333, 81.3333, 81.3333, 82, 81.6667, 82, 81.6667, 83.3333, 
83, 82, 82.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83, 83, 
84.3333, 83.3333, 83.6667, 83.3333, 83, 83.6667, 84, 84.3333, 
84.3333, 84, 84, 84, 82.6667, 84.6667, 84.6667, 85, 85, 84.6667, 
84.3333, 84.6667, 85.3333, 84.3333, 85.3333, 85.3333, 85.3333, 
85, 84.6667, 85.6667, 86.3333, 85.3333, 86.3333, 86, 85.3333, 
85.3333, 86, 85.3333, 86, 87, 86.6667, 85.3333, 86.6667, 87, 
86, 86.6667, 87.3333, 87, 87.6667, 86.6667, 86.3333, 86.3333, 
87.3333, 87, 88, 86.6667, 87.6667, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88, 87.3333, 
87.3333, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88, 88, 87.6667, 88.3333, 87.6667, 
87.6667, 87, 88, 87.6667, 87.3333, 88, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88.3333, 
88.3333, 88, 88, 87.3333, 88.3333, 88.6667, 88.3333, 88.3333, 
88, 89.3333, 89.3333, 89, 88.6667, 88.6667, 88, 89, 88.6667, 
89.6667, 89.3333, 89, 89.3333, 89.6667, 88.6667, 88.3333, 89, 
89, 89.3333, 89.6667, 89.6667, 89.3333, 89.3333, 88.6667, 89, 
88.3333, 90, 88.3333, 90.3333, 89, 89.6667, 90, 89.3333, 89, 
89.6667, 88.6667, 89, 88.6667, 89.6667, 89.3333, 88.6667, 88.6667, 
88.6667, 88, 88, 87, 87.6667, 87, 86.6667, 86.6667, 86.3333, 
86, 85.6667, 85.3333, 84.3333, 83.6667, 84, 83, 82.6667, 82.6667, 
82.6667, 82, 82.3333, 81.6667, 80.6667, 80, 80.3333, 80, 79.3333, 
78.6667, 79, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 76.3333, 75.6667, 77, 75.6667, 
74.6667, 75.3333, 75, 74.3333, 73.3333, 73.6667, 73, 72.3333, 
72.3333, 72.6667, 72.3333, 71.6667, 71, 70.3333, 71.3333, 71, 
69.6667, 70, 69.3333, 69.3333, 69, 68.3333, 68.6667, 68.3333, 
68, 67.6667, 67.3333, 67.6667, 67, 66.6667, 67, 67, 66, 65.6667, 
66, 65.3333, 65.3333, 64.6667, 64.6667, 64.6667, 63.3333, 64, 
64.6667, 64, 64, 63.3333, 62, 63, 63, 62, 61.6667, 61.6667, 62, 
61.6667, 60.3333, 61, 61.3333, 60, 60.6667, 59.3333, 59.6667, 
60, 59.6667, 59.6667, 59.3333, 59.3333, 59.3333, 58.6667, 58, 
58.3333, 57.6667, 58, 58, 57.3333, 57, 57.3333, 57, 57, 56.3333, 
56.3333, 56.6667, 56, 57, 57, 55.3333, 55, 56.3333, 55.3333, 
55.6667, 55.3333, 55.3333, 55.3333, 55, 54, 54.6667, 54, 54, 
54.6667, 53.6667, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 52.3333, 53, 52.3333, 
52.3333, 52, 52.6667, 52.3333, 51, 51.6667, 51.6667, 52, 51.3333, 
51.3333, 51, 51, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.3333, 
50.6667, 50.6667, 50, 50.3333, 50, 50.6667, 50, 50, 49.3333, 
49, 49.3333, 49.3333, 49, 48.6667, 49, 49.3333, 48.6667, 48.3333, 
48.3333, 49, 49, 49, 48.6667, 48.3333, 48.3333, 48, 48, 47.3333, 
48, 48, 47, 47, 48, 47.6667, 46.6667, 46.6667, 47.6667, 47.3333, 
47, 46.6667, 47.3333, 47, 46.3333, 46, 46, 46, 46.3333, 46.3333, 
46, 46, 45.6667, 46, 46.3333, 46, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.6667, 
45.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 45.3333, 44.6667, 
45, 45, 44.6667, 44.6667, 45, 44.6667, 44.3333, 44, 44.3333, 
44.3333, 43.3333, 44.3333, 44, 43.6667, 44, 44, 43.6667, 43.6667, 
44, 43.3333, 43.6667, 43.6667, 43.6667, 43.3333, 43, 42.6667, 
43.3333, 43.3333, 43.3333, 43, 43.3333, 42.3333, 43, 42.6667, 
42.3333, 43, 42.6667, 43, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 
42.6667, 42.6667, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 41.6667, 41.6667, 
42, 41.6667, 41.6667, 42.6667, 41.6667, 41, 41.3333, 42, 41.6667, 
42, 42, 41.6667, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41.3333, 41, 35.6667, 33.6667, 
33.6667, 32.6667, 33.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 30, 29.6667, 30, 29.3333, 29.6667, 29.6667, 
29.3333, 28.3333, 28.6667, 29.6667, 29.6667, 28.6667, 29, 28.6667, 
29.3333, 29, 28.3333, 29, 28.6667, 29, 28.3333, 29.3333, 28.6667, 
28.3333, 29, 28, 28.3333, 29, 28.3333, 28, 28.6667, 28.3333, 
28.3333, 28.6667, 28, 28, 28, 27.6667, 28, 28, 28, 28.3333, 28.3333, 
28, 28, 28.3333, 28, 27.6667, 28, 27.6667, 27.6667, 27.6667, 
27.6667, 27.3333, 28, 27.3333, 27.6667, 27.6667, 27.3333, 27.6667, 
27.3333, 28, 27.6667, 27.6667, 32.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 34.3333, 
33.6667, 33.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 
34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
35, 35.3333, 35.3333, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
35.6667, 35.3333, 35, 35, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35, 35, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 35, 35, 35.3333, 34.6667, 35.3333, 35, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
34.6667, 35, 34.3333, 35.3333, 35, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34.6667, 35, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.6667, 35, 35, 
34.6667, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34.6667, 35, 34.6667, 
34, 35, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 
35, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 35, 34.3333, 34.6667, 
34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 33.6667, 34, 34.3333, 34, 35, 35, 34.6667, 
34, 33.6667, 35, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 
34, 34, 33.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 33.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33.6667, 34.6667, 34, 34, 33.6667, 34.6667, 
34, 33.6667)), row.names = c(NA, 2500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/6356886/680068

Comment: Please provide example input data with a "dip", using `dput(mydata)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, will figure out how to do that and will be back:)