# Calculating peaks in histograms or density functions

Tags: r, histogram

There seem to be a lot of "peaks in density function" threads already, but I don't see one addressing this point specifically. Sorry to duplicate if I missed it.

My problem: Given a vector of 1000 values (sample attached), I would like to identify the peaks in the histogram or density function of the data. From the image of the sample data below , I can see peaks in the histogram at ~0, 6200, and 8400. But I need the obtain the exact values of these peaks, preferably in a simple procedure as I have several thousand of these vectors to process.

[image: Hist and Density Function]

I originally started working with the histogram outputs themselves, but couldn't get any peak-finding command to work properly (like, not at all). I'm not even sure how it would get the **peaks()** command from the **splus2R** package to work on histogram object or on a density object. This would still be my preference, as I would like to identify the exact data value of the max frequency of each peak (as opposed to the density function value, which is slightly different), but I can't figure that one out either.

I would post the sample data themselves, but I can't see a way to do that on here (sorry if I'm just missing it).

Comment: A search for `[r] local maximum` will take you here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6836409/602276

Comment: There doesn't appear to be `peaks` function in the `sm` package

Comment: Here's another via Brian Ripley @ R-help http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02a/archive/33097.html and referenced here at s.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324354/add-a-curve-that-fits-the-peaks-from-a-plot-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your y values are smooth (like in your sample plot), this should find the peaks pretty repeatably:

```
peakx <- x[which(diff(sign(diff(y)))==-2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Finding *Peaks in density functions* is, as already given in the comments, related to [Finding local maxima and minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima) where you can find more solutions. The answer of [chthonicdaemon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133575/10488504) is close to the peak, but each *diff* is reducing the vector length by one.

```
#Create Dataset
x <- c(1,1,4,4,9)

#Estimate Density
d <- density(x)

#Two ways to get highest Peak
d$x[d$y==max(d$y)]  #Gives you all highest Peaks
d$x[which.max(d$y)] #Gives you the first highest Peak

#3 ways to get all Peaks
d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y)>=0)<0)] #This detects also a plateau
d$x[c(F, diff(sign(diff(d$y)))<0)]
d$x[which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))<0)+1]

#In case you also want the height of the peaks
data.frame(d[c("x", "y")])[c(F, diff(diff(d$y)>=0)<0),]

#In case you need a higher "precision"
d <- density(x, n=1e4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are thinking about histograms, maybe you should use the histogram output directly?

```
data <- c(rnorm(100,mean=20),rnorm(100,mean=12))

peakfinder <- function(d){
  dh <- hist(d,plot=FALSE)
  ins <- dh[["intensities"]]
  nbins <- length(ins)
  ss <- which(rank(ins)%in%seq(from=nbins-2,to=nbins)) ## pick the top 3 intensities
  dh[["mids"]][ss]
}

peaks <- peakfinder(data)

hist(data)
sapply(peaks,function(x) abline(v=x,col="red"))
```

This isn't perfect -- for example, it will find just the top bins, even if they are adjacent.  Maybe you could define 'peak' more precisely?  Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: This is essentially what I want to do. But you're right, it grabs every top bin, regardless of whether it's "noise" or a true data "peak". Defining peaks more precisely would certainly help. I was intentionally vague, because I'm not really sure how to do this objectively. I think I may have to look at something like "a peak = top bin where at least 4 of the 6 adjacent bins on each side are descending." That might get out of hand. So, thanks EVERYONE for this starting code. I will go from here and report back if I get something more specific.

Comment: My initial script failed, possibly because "intensities" was not a part of the histogram object. I replaced it with "counts" and the code seemed to work as intended.  

`peakfinder <- function(d){   
dh <- hist(d,plot=FALSE)  
ins <- dh[["counts"]] #original script has "intensities"  
nbins <- length(ins) 
ss <- which(rank(ins)%in%seq(from=nbins-2,to=nbins)) ## pick the top 3 intensities dh[["mids"]][ss]}`

Answer (score 2):

After a good 8+ years later this is still a valid and classic question.
Here's a complete answer now with the excellent clue given by @chthonicdaemon.

```
library(ggplot)
library(data.table)
### I use a preloaded data.table. You can use any data.table with one numeric column x.
### Extract counts & breaks of the histogram bins. 
### I have taken breaks as 40 but you can take any number as needed.
### But do keep a large number of breaks so that you get multiple peaks.
counts <- hist(dt1$x,breaks = 40)$counts
breaks <- hist(dt1$x, breaks = 40)$breaks
### Note: the data.table `dt1` should contain at least one numeric column, x

### now name the counts vector with the corresponding breaks 
### note: the length of counts is 1 less than the breaks
names(counts) <- breaks[-length(breaks)]

### Find index for those counts that are the peaks 
### (see previous classic clue to take a double diff)
### note: the double diff causes the 2 count shrink, hence
#### I have added a FALSE before and after the results 
### to align the T/F vector with the count vector

peak_indx <- c(F,diff(sign(c(diff(counts))))==-2,F) %>% which()
topcounts <- counts[peak_indx]
topbreaks <- names(topcounts) %>% as.numeric()

### Now let's use ggplot to plot the histogram along with visualised peaks

dt1 %>%     
ggplot() + 
geom_histogram(aes(x),bins = 40,col="grey51",na.rm = T) + 
geom_vline(xintercept = topbreaks + 50,lty = 2) 
# adjust the value 50 to bring the lines in the centre
```

[image: Output histogram with peaks marked]