# "Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = ) : no such index at level 1" assigning for loop result to list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list of numerical vectors. For each vector I want to determine the x-values for the kernal density peaks using a for loop. Running the for loop when printing the results works fine. When trying to store the results in a list I get the following error:

> "Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) <
>   0)]) : no such index at level 2"

The Error message in my original code

> returns: "... no such index at level 1".

Can anyone help me fixing this error? The code for extracting the x-values for the kernal density peaks came from [Calculating peaks in histograms or density functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133297/calculating-peaks-in-histograms-or-density-functions), third answer.

```
set.seed(1234)

x <- list(col1 = c(rnorm(100, mean = 3), rnorm(100, mean = 4)),
          col2 = c(rnorm(100, mean = 3), rnorm(100, mean = 4)))

# Works fine
output <- vector("list", length(x))
for (i in (x)){
d <- density(i)
d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)] %>% print()
}

# Does not work
output <- vector("list", length(x))
for (i in (x)){
d <- density(i)
d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)] -> output[[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `x` is a list you need to loop over its index to store the output.

```
output <- vector("list", length(x))

for (i in seq_along(x)){
#Can also use 
#for (i in 1:length(x)){
  d <- density(x[[i]])
  d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)] -> output[[i]]
}
```

---

Alternatively, using `lapply` would automatically give you a list

```
lapply(x, function(i) {
   d <- density(i)
   d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)]
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly Ronak! Can you explain why assiging using "for (i in x)" works for printing, but not for assigning to a list?

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel When you are trying to assign value for first iteration `i` is 1st element of `x` i.e `x[[1]]`. So what you are trying to do is `output[[x[[1]]]]` which gives you the same error as you are getting now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
output <- vector("list", length(x))
j=0
for (i in (x)){
j=j+1
d <- density(i)
d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)] -> output[[j]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, `i` is the elements in `x`, not the index of element. If you want to update `output` by index, you can try the code below

```
output <- list()
for (i in (x)){
d <- density(i)
d$x[c(F, diff(diff(d$y) >= 0) < 0)] -> output[length(output)+1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After being hit with a similar `` Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, `` ...`, value =` ...`) : no such index at level 1` error message myself and ending up here, I wondered why the error message isn't just:

> you are trying to use an element instead of an index to index a list

or (more likely):

> you are trying to index multiple elements of a list with `[[` when you should be using `[` instead

So I went towards `` ?`[[<-` ``  for an answer; and indeed TIL:

> `[[` can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index `i` is a vector of length `p`, `alist[[i]]` is equivalent to `alist[[i1]]`...`[[ip]]` providing all but the final indexing results in a list.

For example:

```r
# If we create a list containing vector
a <- list(x = 4:6, y = "Hi") ; a
#> $x
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] "Hi"

# We can directly access the nested element with a vector index
a[[c(1, 2)]]
#> [1] 5

# equivalently to the recursive call
a[[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 5
```

```
# we can assign elements at new indices to lists
a[[3]] <- "World" ; a
#> $x
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] "Hi"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "World"

# even using vector indices
a[[c(3,2)]] <- "!" ; a
#> $x
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] "Hi"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "World" "!"

# but not recursively , i.e. the element in the second to last layer needs to 
# exist already (think of `mkdir` without `-p`)
a[[c(4,2)]] <- "Goodbye!"
#> Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, c(4, 2), value = "Goodbye!"): no such index at level 1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you end up here and would have appreciated something like above hints to be part of the error message, let me know and I'll see what I can do...