# how to run 2 way mixed anova with type 3 error using for loop in R?

Tags: r, anova

My statistical analysis design is multiple 2-way mixed ANOVAs. Independent variables are Team (i.e., between factor) and Box (i.e., within factor). Since the number of participants doesn't match with each other, I would like to use `aov_car` or `car::Anova` instead of `aov` or `rstatix::anova_test` to calculate omega squared. When I ran `aov_car` individually, it returned the result without error (a warning message appears though) as follows:

```
aov_car(data2[[4]] ~ Team*Box+Error(ID/Box), data = data2)
**Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: Team**
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: [[.data2
    Effect    df  MSE      F  ges p.value
1     Team 2, 24 0.03   1.07 .081    .360
2      Box 1, 24 0.00 5.08 * .003    .034
3 Team:Box 2, 24 0.00   1.98 .002    .160
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

aov_car(ContactTime ~ Team*Box+Error(ID/Box), data = data2)
Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: Team
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: ContactTime
    Effect    df  MSE      F  ges p.value
1     Team 2, 24 0.03   1.07 .081    .360
2      Box 1, 24 0.00 5.08 * .003    .034
3 Team:Box 2, 24 0.00   1.98 .002    .160
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But, when I but this code in the for loop and change the number to the index (i.e., i), r returns error.

```
for (i in 4:39){
  m <- aov(data2[[i]] ~ Team*Box+Error(ID/Box), data = data2)
  cat(paste('\nDependent var:', c[i], '\n'))
  print(summary(m))
  a <- omega_squared(m, partial = TRUE)
  print(a)
}
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = value) : no such index at level 1
```

Is there anyone who knows how to run these multiple ANOVAs with type 3 error using for loop?

---

I have added a reproducible example below:

```
library(afex)
library(effectsize)

dat <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1:27,1:27)),
                   within = factor(c(rep('Pre',27),rep('Post',27))),
                  between=factor(c(rep('a',10),rep('b',9),rep('c',8),
                                   rep('a',10),rep('b',9),rep('c',8))),
                  var1=rnorm(54),
                  var2=rnorm(54),
                  var3=rnorm(54))

head(dat)
  id within between       var1       var2       var3
1  1    Pre       a  0.3665630  0.1497566  0.7439017
2  2    Pre       a -0.8780057  1.9250468 -2.0035645
3  3    Pre       a -0.2363018 -0.8559707 -3.5480145
4  4    Pre       a -0.7437626  1.6332548  0.1368730
5  5    Pre       a  0.9967578  0.1443508  0.8658533
6  6    Pre       a  0.8458148 -0.8844405 -0.2159427

tail(dat)
   id within between        var1       var2       var3
49 22   Post       c  0.34770666  0.2485870 -0.2874768
50 23   Post       c  0.32818704 -1.0625061  0.1099009
51 24   Post       c  0.02007684  0.1477275 -1.7305074
52 25   Post       c -0.35504783  0.9240360  0.9997529
53 26   Post       c  1.27313762 -1.5641873  1.8980272
54 27   Post       c  0.51176220  1.1039483  0.3516720

c <- paste(colnames(dat))

for (i in 4:6){
  m <- aov_car(dat[[i]] ~ between*within+Error(id/within), data = dat)
  cat(paste('\nDependent var:', c[i], '\n'))
  print(summary(m))
  a <- omega_squared(m, partial = TRUE)
  print(a)
}

Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = value) : no such index at level 1
```

Comment: For the error that you have, the solution here might resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59626119/6288065. If it doesn't, please provide a reproducible example that we can use.  We would need to see which part of your code is causing this error. E.g., is it the second line or the third line in the for loop? Try commenting out or removing the third line and let us know what happens. Also, what is `c` in `c[i]`?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @LC-datascientist `c` is the column names of the dataset. I have added a reproducible example.

Comment: @RonakShah I have added a reproducible example. Thank you,

Comment: How do you run this without a loop for one example? I was trying `m <- aov_car(var1~ between*within+Error(id/within), data = dat)` and `a <- omega_squared(m, partial = TRUE)` `a` returns `Error in cat(insight::format_table(x, digits = digits)) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`

Comment: @RonakShah I could run this code outside of loop. I didn't get an error when I used this code as follows: `m2 <- aov_car(var1 ~ between*within+Error(id/within), data = dat)
summary(m2)
a <- omega_squared(m2, partial = TRUE)` I just got an message like 'Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: between' following the `m2` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the formula as string and convert it to formula using `as.formula`.

```
cols <- grep('var', names(dat), value = TRUE)
result <- vector('list', length(cols))

for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
  m <- aov_car(as.formula(sprintf('%s~between*within+Error(id/within)', cols[i])), data = dat)
  cat(paste('\nDependent var:', cols[i], '\n'))
  print(summary(m))
  result[[i]] <- omega_squared(m, partial = TRUE)
  print(result[[i]])
}
```